# Error 400 on some topicId queries with YouTube API V3

Tags: http, google-api, youtube-api, freebase, http-status-code-400

I've noticed that the V3 API returns a 400 error for some values of topicId, while it generally works fine.

### E.g.

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=10&type=video&key={API-KEY}&topicId=%2Fm%2F0k_qlf`

Error 400: Invalid combination of search filters and/or restrictions.

---

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=10&type=video&key={API-KEY}&topicId=%2Fm%2F01vrncs`

Works fine

Anything I've done wrong, or is that an error in the API itself?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The example you provided was not an 'mid' that YouTube API can return information about. That was the expected behavior. Just keep in mind, not all freebase topics will necessarily have video information.

Next time if you think it's a bug, feel free to file an public bug under `http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/list?`

Cheers

Comment: Ok, I see. An empty response might be better than a 400 error in that case? I'll use the bugtracker in the future.